# Replacement of RaspberryPi

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi, arm, cpu, processor

I'm working with a learning project where I use an IMU sensor unit connected with Raspberry Pi 4B via UART. I receive data on Raspi's serial port and later I use that data to display it on a self made GUI. Now my question is:

How can I build this project on a PCB board? **I want to replace raspberry pi with a processor or micro-controller or any other chip which can do similar processing**. **I would also like to know if it is possible to have UART and SPI (or CAN bus) on this pcb board, so that I can further extend the usage of this board.**

Extra( if possible):
Until now I have programmed my GUI code in Python, so is it also possible to still use python for this new processor, so that I will have less software stuff to care about? In case its not possible, Im open for other programming languages also.

Comment: Regarding the choice of controller: If you want to go down the learning route, you can use microcontrollers which support 'micropython'. This is limited -- There are only certain python libraries supported and you will need to use a microcontroller with a large enough memory to hold the libraries and python interpreter. Adafruit and several other manufacturers sell controllers which support micropython.  Alternatively, you may want to transition to Arduino, which can support your UART/SPI protocols, however you will likely need to switch to C/C++.

Comment: Designing your own micro linux computer on a PCB is not practical for a beginner. You can either re-imagine your project using a microcontroller, or add a socket for a separate linux computer such as the raspberry pi compute module. Designing graphical GUIS on a microcontroller is not easy either. You may want to switch to a simple text LCD or serial output while you're learning.

Comment: But this are two parts. Part one is to get the data from the IMU and create a useful package to push the data-package to a PC. Part two is to make this data visible and this can be done in Python. Part one is better done in C with a tiny microcontroller, maybe STM32F1 or a AVR-µC.

Comment: You are thinking about the PCB board but you should be thinking about what kind of chip or module to use on the board. Unfortunately **I** can't help answer your question because I'm not sure which platforms are suitable for displaying GUIs.

Comment: how is this GUI displayed - via HDMI? HDMI basically requires a GPU in order to push the pixels fast enough as they must be sent very fast with specific timing. There are other types of screens with built-in controllers that any microcontroller can send commands to at its own pace - such as (just off the top of my head) screens based on SSD1306, and the ubiquitous 16x2 character LCDs.

Answer (score 1):

Video output from microcontrollers is a bit tricky because the video interfaces you're used to - like HDMI - work by sending all the pixel data over and over and over, and that's a lot of data. You have to keep it up, the whole time the computer is on, or else the screen goes blank. And this makes sense because this is also how screens work - each pixel has to be constantly refreshed or else it quickly fades to off.

Ancient computers (Commodore 64 style) had to build the whole design of the computer system around the video output, to make sure the video would always have the right data at the right time no matter what, and that experience is also common with microcontrollers. It may be possible a lot of the time, it may even be a fun idea to play with - see [Uzebox](https://uzebox.org/hardware.htm) - but if you want to actually get stuff done you probably want something more convenient.

Making a GUI on the Raspberry Pi isn't hard because it contains a GPU which keeps refreshing the screen while your own code works at its own pace.

Enter: screens with built-in GPUs. Of course, these don't do 3D graphics like the Raspberry Pi one. They do just enough to keep the screen refreshed, and accept the update commands from your microcontroller at your microcontroller's pace. If you Google-search a term like 'arduino lcd display' you will find many.

I'll show some examples. [These 16x2 character LCDs](https://lastminuteengineers.com/arduino-1602-character-lcd-tutorial/?utm_content=cmp-true) are *everywhere* and you might have seen some in commercial products before. As you can see by the pin labelling, there is an 8-bit data bus and some control signals, although typically they can also be used in 4-bit or 1-bit mode, so only a few pins on your Arduino are needed. Your Arduino sends it X/Y coordinates and ASCII letters, and a chip inside the display handles the rest.

If you're looking for something bigger or more flexible, my own Google search suggested [this one](https://www.reichelt.de/de/de/arduino-shield-display-3-5-320-x-480-ard-shd-lcd3-5-p291375.html?PROVID=2788&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIyrqTs8ii_gIVC4xoCR0yOw9wEAQYAyABEgJhW_D_BwE&&r=1), 3.5 inches wide with 320x200 pixels. It has an [ILI9486](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/7/78/ILI9486_Datasheet.pdf) controller chip. I didn't read the datasheet in full detail but it appears that with this chip supports several protocols (I2C, SPI, parallel) and it is operated by selecting a rectangle of pixels and then writing all of the pixels in that rectangle. Some controllers have commands like "draw a rectangle" but it appears this one doesn't - you draw pixels individually.

Again, there are many, so do your own search and don't just rely on the specific one that came up in my search.

Answer (score 0):

A Raspberry PI is perhaps the simplest means of generating graphical output. If you need graphics, and don't feel like rewriting the software, then you probably want to stick with PI, and build your cicuit as a shield for the PI.

Otherwise, there are several amateur-friendly options that can be built on a single PCB:

1. Raspberry Pico: it can generate VGA output using one core, or HDMI output using two cores. So, for HDMI, use two RP2040 chips: one to generate the video output, another to run MicroPython in one core for high-level code, and the other core can run the C or C++ code that generates the graphic bitmaps and sends them over to the other chip for display.
2. Parallax Propeller II: you get everything on one chip, since it has 8 cores, is quite fast (100s of MIPS per core), and has hardware support for HDMI encoding. I don't recall if there's a Python implementation for it, but you can certainly implement your code in C, and then the HDMI output is a pre-made object that you just plug-in. You can also implement the code in the Spin language - a high-level language with "built in" support on Propellers.

As a matter of personal preference: if you asked me today to design it "pi-less" for "yesterday", I would go with Propeller II with external HyperRAM. Would be a bit more work on RP2040 since there's no pre-existing code that does cross-chip graphics, and having RP2040 output HDMI takes almost the resources of an entire chip. For $1 that's still a dirt-cheap HDMI generator if you ask me though.

If Rasperry Pi foundation ends up selling the RPI 4 chips, then of course you could just reimplement a part of RPI4 on a board together with your other stuff.